# How to display my background-image in my html/css?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've seen another topic about my issue, but it doesn't resolve it, I try to put a background image for my portfolio but it doesn't work. I don't understand why, do you have an idea ?

my code:

html:

```html
 <div class="main">
    <div class="navbar container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center"> 
        <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x firstIcon mr-4"> <span class="txtIcon"> Project</span></i> 
        <i class="fas fa-check-square fa-3x mx-4"> <span class="txtIcon2"> Skills</span></i>
        <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-3x ml-4"> <span class="txtIcon3"> Contact</span></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
css:

.main{
background-image: url(../img/dev-dots.png);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;


}

.navbar{
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: purple;
    position: fixed;
}
```

PS: Sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: edit : there is a mistake in my code :

Comment: <div class="main">
    <div class="navbar container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center"> 
        
        <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x firstIcon mr-4"> <span class="txtIcon"> Project</span></i> 
        <i class="fas fa-check-square fa-3x mx-4"> <span class="txtIcon2"> Skills</span></i>
        <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-3x ml-4"> <span class="txtIcon3"> Contact</span></i>


    
    
    </div>
</div>

Comment: i think your problem is your css class's  background-img url relative path is incorrect.
maybe post your project file for check.

Comment: If this is your index.html try `url("img/dev-dots.png")`

Comment: Code looks correct, check if you get any error in your browser's console, you might be using the wrong path in the `background-image`

Comment: You are using some kind of CSS framework/library and you need to tag that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
  background-image: url('http://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p640x640/86969955_2219297081712551_4370094468804640768_o.jpg?_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=RXVSJ86AsuoAX_l1w_j&_nc_ht=scontent-vie1-1.xx&_nc_tp=6&oh=f79e4654f5cee0a184fa73d9faa0af49&oe=5EFBD055');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 200px;


}

.navbar{
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: purple;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
    <div class="navbar container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center"> 
        <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x firstIcon mr-4"> <span class="txtIcon"> Project</span></i> 
        <i class="fas fa-check-square fa-3x mx-4"> <span class="txtIcon2"> Skills</span></i>
        <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-3x ml-4"> <span class="txtIcon3"> Contact</span></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what you looking for? The fixed attribute made the container not expanding, so no background to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your div element with class 'main' doesn't have any height. The background image will not show because of this.

You can do one of these options:

Give it a fixed height (not recommended)

```
.main {
  height: 100px
}
```

Add block elements to your navbar so main gets it height automaticaly

```
 .navbar {
display: block
}
```

Don't use position fixed in this case as well.

Last but not least, lose the backgroundcolor of navbar, this wil lay on top of de backgroundimage of main.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/14/04/20/old-city-4847469_960_720.jpg');
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;


}

.navbar{
    height: 20vh;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="navbar container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center"> 
        <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x firstIcon mr-4"> <span class="txtIcon"> Project</span></i> 
        <i class="fas fa-check-square fa-3x mx-4"> <span class="txtIcon2"> Skills</span></i>
        <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-3x ml-4"> <span class="txtIcon3"> Contact</span></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are providing the wrong path. try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.main{
background-image: url(http://www.cagbd.org/assets/upload/logo/1124d2b92e3b8f44b1c8f21cfebc6dae.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

}

.navbar{
    height: 10vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
 <div class="main">
    <div class="navbar container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center"> 
        <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x firstIcon mr-4"> <span class="txtIcon"> Project</span></i> 
        <i class="fas fa-check-square fa-3x mx-4"> <span class="txtIcon2"> Skills</span></i>
        <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-3x ml-4"> <span class="txtIcon3"> Contact</span></i>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
  background-image: url(../img/dev-dots.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Even if this provides an answer to OP's problem, this will not considered as an answer without a good explanation, and will be consider low quality post, which will likely be deleted after some time. So, please add an explanation along with the code.